# What and how to run tests under OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Under each of OpenCV module there is /test subfolder. How those test are executed individually, manually or automatically ?  There is an option on perf test as well? How to identify which tests and perf test are run if that build option is enabled? Actually question goes to explanation of test for OpenCV in high detail.

Comment: I don't know much about it, but I would recommend you to take a look at [this document](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/QA_in_OpenCV) and check how C.I. is done on [pullrequest.opencv.org](https://pullrequest.opencv.org) ([example](https://pullrequest.opencv.org/buildbot/builders/precommit_linux64/builds/19964))

Comment: After the installation of opencv (I think you need contrib and extra) there should be a script in /usr/local/bin called opencv_run_all_tests.sh. Just run it with sudo and it will output the passed and failed tests. If you want detailed explanation you can try looking into the code for each test.